# Weird behaviour when Goodreads scraping (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I'm trying to scrape Goodreads and more specifically Goodreads editions by giving some ISBNs as input. However, I get an error and not even at the same step every time of the code running process:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:xxx.py", line 47, in <module>
    ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn)
  File "C:xxx.py", line 30, in get_editions_details
    ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Everything should be correct, the div class is the correct one and it seems like is there for all books. I checked with every browser and the page looks the same to me. I don't know if it's because of a deprecated library or something at this point.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_isbn():
    isbns = ['9780544176560', '9781796898279', '9788845278518', '9780374165277', '9781408839973', '9788838919916', '9780349121994', '9781933372006', '9781501167638', '9781427299062', '9788842050285', '9788807018985', '9780340491263', '9789463008594', '9780739349083', '9780156011594', '9780374106140', '9788845251436', '9781609455910']
    return isbns


def get_page(base_url, data):
    try:
        r = requests.get(base_url, params=data)
    except Exception as e:
        r = None
        print(f"Server responded: {e}")
    return r


def get_editions_details(isbn):
    # Create the search URL with the ISBN of the book
    data = {'q': isbn}
    book_url = get_page("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
    # Parse the markup with Beautiful Soup
    soup = bs(book_url.text, 'lxml')

    # Retrieve from the book's page the link for other editions
    # and the total number of editions

    ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")

    ed_link = f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}"
    ed_num = ed_item.text.strip().split(' ')[-1].strip('()')

    # Return a tuple with all the informations
    return ((ed_link, int(ed_num), isbn))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the ISBNs from the user
    isbns = get_isbn()

    # Check all the ISBNs
    for isbn in isbns:
        ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn)
```

Comment: I just did a quick search on Goodreads in Chrome and the returned html did not have `otherEditionsLink`

Comment: There is a div class `otherEditionsLink` if you click "more details and inspect the code of the link "Other Editions" like [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39700697-il-nome-della-rosa). Don't you have it? I see it in Chrome as well

Comment: There is a `<div class='infoBoxRowTitle otherEditions'>
<div class='otherEditionsLink'>
<a href="/work/editions/3138328-il-nome-della-rosa">Other Editions (225)</a>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: The book I searched for does not have any other editions. You probably should handle that case.

Comment: I have... I deleted the ones with no other editions but still

Comment: I'm guessing the error you have is here: `ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")`. If `soup.find` returns `None` you can't call `find("a")` on that.

Comment: I know, idk how to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check return values.

```
book_url = get_page("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
soup = bs(book_url.text, 'lxml')
ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")
```

In these statements, if any of the returned values are `None`, you will get an error when you try to call a member function. So if `soup` is `None`, for example, you would be doing something like `None.find(....)`, which is obviously wrong.

In the last line, for example, you can fix this by breaking it up into 2 parts:

```
if ed_item := soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink"):
    if ed_item := ed_item.find("a"):
        ....other code here....
```

As long as `soup` is valid, this code won't try to call a function on a `None` value.

There are other ways to handle this situation. One is to just `return` on failure:

```
if (ed_item := soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink")) == None:
    return None
if (ed_item := ed_item.find("a")) == None:
    return None
....other code here....
```

Another option is to use exceptions:

```
try:
    ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")
    ....other code here....
except AttributeError:
    return None
```